# "Last Modified" won't apply to custom variables

Tags: eleventy

[According to the 11ty docs](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/dates/), the "Last Modified" string should be replaced for the file modification file.

However, this doesn't seem to be the case.

```
---
date: 2021-07-12
modified: Last Modified
---
```

No matter if we access through `page` like this: `{{ page.modified }}` or directly `{{ modified }}`.

The `date` variable works as expected.

I would like to have both dates, published + modified to use on the `application/ld+json` schema.

I also noticed that if I do this, then it shows the modified date correctly:

```
---
date: Last Modified
---
```

Are we forced to use the "Last Modified" constant on the `date` variable for it to work?

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure that the "Last Modified" magic value only works for `date`, not arbitrary front matter values. If you want to have the last modified value plus a published date, why not use different front matter keys?

```
---
date: Last Modified
publishedDate: 2021-10-01
---
```

Comment: It just seems a bit weird to me that "date" means "last modified" :)

Comment: heh, agreed. I'm not a fan of 'magic' like this usually. shrug.